# How to host based routing different version in same AWS EB application

Tags: amazon-web-services, routes, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

The question come from here that recently I am required to start a new project using AWS, while I was GCP developer before.

In GCP, I can deploy my application to AppEngine(similar to EB) with versioning like `gcloud app deploy settings.yaml --version dev`. Such that I can have host based routing on two links --

> my-project.xxxx.com
>
> dev.my-project.xxxx.com

Such that I can let others to have a domain for testing **without starting an new instance**, sharing all environment settings, dbs and storage.

---

However, when I come to AWS, it seems the story is completely different.

I try to follow this guide https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-host-based-routing-support-for-aws-application-load-balancers/, but it is just for routing to **different instances**.

By the way I know that EB application can have multiple versions, so is it possible to do something like

> my-project.xxxx.com -> go to default version
>
> dev.my-project.xxxx.com -> go to version with tag 'dev'

---

So 2 questions,

1. Can I achieve what I want?
2. If can't, is starting another EB instance for testing only choice?

Comment: if storage, rds and env the same, what is the difference then? you can clone your prod env to dev, it will setup new elb and instance

Comment: @NeverBe, actually storage is not exactly the same, I have this question because I want front-end development can test some small js changes. Let's say I change some syntax in a js file and want to test it on other platform, is it convenient and cheaper to reuse the existing eb instead of starting a new one?

Comment: EB supports to run many apps in the same ENV, you need to read the docs